# laravel 5.4 passport token used in resource

Tags: laravel-5.4, laravel-passport

I created a users resource for my RESTAPI and now i am able to register a user.

After that i installed passport and i am getting the token.

When i tried to accesss

```
'/user'
```

I got as unauthorized.

When i pasted the token in Authorization Header, i was prompted with api_token column is missing, on which i updated my migration for api_token column with string 60.

Again when i tried to access '/user' i am still getting as unauthorized.

Followingly, let me say i got posts generated as resource. I want my moderator or admin only to have delete access not to the user. How can i achieve it? In short, how to control the authorization for resource routes.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the api middleware and auth:api? Submitting a X-CSRF-TOKEN as well? GET or POST? Need more info to help you out here.